# Iterating through strings, adding to list and then accessing

Tags: python, string, list, iteration

My variable x holds the following data and I want to extract only the links (https://...)

```
1758162
hd
video/mp4
2160
3840
23.976
https://player.vimeo.com/external/479728625.hd.mp4?s=84b5a866b5b24de0e1d3bc20fbd0a98d544bda93&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761
1200135
hd
video/mp4
1080
1920
29.97
https://player.vimeo.com/external/449630779.hd.mp4?s=2d49b6c1ec0a2fe9b65b424a112839aba1ae5437&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=57447761
```

so I have:

```
d = []
if "https" in str(x):
   d.append(x)
else:
   pass
print(d[0])
```

However, when I do print(d[0]) it gives me both of the https links, instead of just the first one. What am I doing wrong? I just want to see the first https..

Comment: Please share what `x` actually is. Is it a list of strings? You showed what data it's holding, but it's unclear how exactly, and it's likely that your call to `str(x)` is causing the problem. Also, the result probably contains more than just the two links, but rather all the content?

Comment: If `x` is _all_ of those values, then of course `"https" in str(x)` is going to be true...

Answer (score 1):

if x is a starting this should do the trick

```
print([row for row in x.split("\n") if row.startswith("https")])
```

the output will be:

```
['https://player.vimeo.com/external/479728625.hd.mp4?s=84b5a866b5b24de0e1d3bc20fbd0a98d544bda93&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761', 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/449630779.hd.mp4?s=2d49b6c1ec0a2fe9b65b424a112839aba1ae5437&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=57447761']
```

Comment: there are 2 links in the x variable

Comment: and both of them are in the list that the code printed 
if my answer helped you could you consider marking it as the answer? 
and if you have any followup questions feel free to ask here :)

Answer (score 0):

We have to assume that `x` is some list or other iterable of strings. You check if 'http' is in a line, but it might make more sense to check that it starts with that.

The problem is that you do this:

```
if "http" in str(x):
```

This takes all of `x` and turns the whole thing into a string. You instead want to check each line one at a time and only add the ones that match.

```
lines = [
    '1758162',
    'hd',
    'video/mp4',
    '2160',
    '3840',
    '23.976',
    'https://player.vimeo.com/external/479728625.hd.mp4?s=84b5a866b5b24de0e1d3bc20fbd0a98d544bda93&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761',
    '1200135',
    'hd',
    'video/mp4',
    '1080',
    '1920',
    '29.97',
    'https://player.vimeo.com/external/449630779.hd.mp4?s=2d49b6c1ec0a2fe9b65b424a112839aba1ae5437&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=57447761'
]

d = []
for line in lines:
    if str(line).startswith('http'):  # added because you say lines has int as well
        d.append(line)

print(d[0])  # you say you're only interested in the first of the results
```

Of course you could also just:

```
d = [line for line in lines if str(line).startswith('http')]
```

If your `x` is not in fact a list already, but a single piece of text, you can get `lines` like this:

```
lines = x.split('\n')  # \n represents a line ending
```

Comment: I think that some of the data in x is int. So it gives me an error saying that 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: Also, I want to print just the first link. When doing print(d[0]) I get multiple.

Comment: To avoid problems with the integers, adding in the `str()` in the right place helps. As for printing just the first link, using `d[0]` makes sense, but the problem is in the rest of your code. I've adjusted the answer. But you should really update your question with the needed info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex.

Example:

```
import re 

st='''\
1758162
hd
video/mp4
2160
3840
23.976
https://player.vimeo.com/external/479728625.hd.mp4?s=84b5a866b5b24de0e1d3bc20fbd0a98d544bda93&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761
1200135
hd
video/mp4
1080
1920
29.97
https://player.vimeo.com/external/449630779.hd.mp4?s=2d49b6c1ec0a2fe9b65b424a112839aba1ae5437&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=57447761''' 


print(
    re.findall(r'^https:.*', st, re.M)
)
```

Prints:

```
['https://player.vimeo.com/external/479728625.hd.mp4?s=84b5a866b5b24de0e1d3bc20fbd0a98d544bda93&profile_id=172&oauth2_token_id=57447761', 'https://player.vimeo.com/external/449630779.hd.mp4?s=2d49b6c1ec0a2fe9b65b424a112839aba1ae5437&profile_id=175&oauth2_token_id=57447761']
```